# Regex for space check with unicode characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have one little regex `^(\w+\s?)*\s*$` for validation spaces in input field on site

Problem with it is unicode characters

```
"           " => fail
"          a" => fail
"abc ab  abc" => fail
"abc abc abc" => true
"ąbc abc abc" => fail #problem
```

I was trying some like ^(\p{L}\s?)*\s*$ but this does not work.

Comment: `\w+` only permits a single sequential series of word characters, not 3 words, your pattern doesn't really make sense? https://regex101.com/r/xjHOQT/1

Comment: What Unicode characters do you have problems with? Perhaps they were lost on copy/paste but your snippet only has good old U+0020.

Comment: From polish alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of \w which means [0-9a-zA-Z_], I think you could use something like \S which matches any non-whitespace character.

Comment: I should warn that some more unicode characters are classified as whitespace character. If you need such strict check, you should consider it.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character